# How to configure Goland to use -test.coverprofile=[path] instead of -test.coverprofile [path]?

Tags: test-coverage, goland

In order to run my program I have to give it some arguments: `./main list` or `./main serve --config=.env.test`.
I have to write integration tests for that. In order to see test coverage I click "Run with Coverage" button in Goland IDE.

When I click "Run with Coverage" I see Goland executes these commands:

```
/usr/lib/go/bin/go test -c -coverpkg=./... -covermode=atomic -i -test.run=TestMain -o /tmp/___coverage_test main #gosetup
/usr/lib/go/bin/go tool test2json -t /tmp/___coverage_test -test.v -test.coverprofile /home/admin/.GoLand2019.3/system/coverage/main$coverage_test.out serve --config=.env.test #gosetup
```

This gives me an error: `Error: unknown command "/home/admin/.GoLand2019.3/system/coverage/main$coverage_test.out" for "app"`.

But if I manually run:

```
/usr/lib/go/bin/go tool test2json -t /tmp/___coverage_test -test.v -test.coverprofile=/home/admin/.GoLand2019.3/system/coverage/main$coverage_test.out serve --config=.env.test #gosetup
```

it works fine.

How can I say Goland to use `-test.coverprofile=[path]` instead of `-test.coverprofile [path]`. I need that `=` here.

Comment: What Go version are you using?

Comment: 1.14.1 (https://i.imgur.com/s4ue9og.png)

Comment: Sorry for the delay. We cannot replicate this. Please open an issue on our tracker at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/Go and we'll see if we can get more information from the IDE logs that might be of help. As usual, please upgrade your IDE as the latest version is 2020.1.2 and you appear to run 2019.3.x